# What is the protocol for editing the tagged answer to include valuable details from other answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I thought for sure I'd read a question here on Meta that addressed this already, but I couldn't find it again.

In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13252/whats-the-full-form-significance-of-uss-iss-prefixes-in-name-of-star-trek-s) I answered one part of the question, however there was a second part about the significance of the designations that was not addressed. My answer was tagged as the answer, however, parallel answers do somewhat address the secondary part. I'd like to edit my answer to include similar details, but am uncertain as to the protocol and general acceptance of doing so.

In other words, is it frowned upon to flesh out existing answers with details garnered or informed by other answers? My instinct says editing answers to provide more details is acceptable, regardless of where the additional detail came from, however I'm uncertain if that's desirable by the SFF.SE community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Improving your answer is encouraged. If you used material from other answers (be it from the same question or not), acknowledge them in your own. If that's a lot of material, it may be preferable to just give a quick summary and link to the other answers.